# Decode jwt token in angular?

Tags: angular, jwt

I've got a requirement to decode jwt token which sent by API during login time.
How to decode **jwt token** in angular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can decode **JWT token** in angular for that you need to have "@auth0/angular-jwt" npm module installed in your angular app.
The decode of JWT has following steps

1. install "@auth0/angular-jwt" module
   `npm i @auth0/angular-jwt -s`
2. Register  **JwtModule** module into your app.module.ts
   `import { JwtModule } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";` 
   under **imports:[]** section add this

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter:  () => localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      }
    })
```

3. use "JwtHelperService" in your component or wher ever its required for your use.

Code would look like below.

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
 constructor(private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {}
 someMethod(){
   const token = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
 }
```

**NOTE:**
**JwtHelperService** has other methods too, use according to your need.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think an external module is necessary to decode a JWT token. It could be done with JS [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) function.

Here is a general function using JS `atob()` with `Array#split`, `Array#map` and `Array#reduce`

```js
function decodeToken(token) {
  const _decodeToken = (token) => {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(atob(token));
    } catch {
      return;
    }
  };
  return token
    .split('.')
    .map(token => _decodeToken(token))
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (!!curr) acc = { ...acc, ...curr };
      return acc;
    }, Object.create(null));
}
```

Here is a working snippet

```js
function decodeToken(token) {
  const _decodeToken = (token) => {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(atob(token));
    } catch {
      return;
    }
  };
  return token
    .split('.')
    .map(token => _decodeToken(token))
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (!!curr) acc = { ...acc, ...curr };
      return acc;
    }, Object.create(null));
}

const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c';

console.log(decodeToken(token));
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular11-token-decode?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Exactly, if you only need to decode the token then the above example is enough. If you need to also validate the token then it's best to use libraries like `@auth0/angular-jwt` or `@curity/jwt-validation`